# GStreamer gst_buffer_make_writable seg fault and refcount "hack"

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I implemented a custom metadata structure for the buffer in GStreamer. To use this structure I created a pad probe and access the buffer with `auto buffer = gst_pad_probe_info_get_buffer(info);`, where `info` is a `GstPadProbeInfo *info`.

Most elements of the pipeline have writeable buffers and I have no problems with them, but when trying to access the buffer in the sink pad of the queue element it appears that this buffer is not writeable. I already tried to use the `buffer = gst_buffer_make_writable(buffer);` method but with no luck. I get segmentation faults when using it. I also get a segmentation fault if I just try to create another temporary writable buffer: `auto *tmpBuffer = gst_buffer_make_writable(buffer);`

> (rtspserver:23806): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 09:23:03.442:
> gst_buffer_get_sizes_range: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed
>
> (rtspserver:23806): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 09:23:03.442:
> gst_buffer_copy_into: assertion 'bufsize >= offset' failed
>
> (rtspserver:23806): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 09:23:03.442:
> gst_buffer_get_sizes_range: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed
>
> (rtspserver:23806): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 09:23:03.443:
> gst_buffer_extract: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed
>
> (rtspserver:23806): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 09:23:03.443:
> gst_buffer_foreach_meta: assertion 'buffer != NULL' failed
>
> (rtspserver:23806): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 09:23:03.443:
> gst_buffer_append_region: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buf2)' failed
> Segmentation fault

Another thing I tried is to copy the buffer to another temporary buffer `auto *tmpBuffer = gst_buffer_copy(buffer);`, but then I also have problem with overwriting `gst_buffer_replace(&buffer, tmpBuffer);` the original buffer.

I found a solution/hack: I increase the refcount `buffer = gst_buffer_ref(buffer);` at the queue element (from 2 to 3) and then access the buffer directly without checking it's writability. After that I unref the buffer `gst_buffer_unref(buffer);`. This seems to work and I would like to know why. If I do not increase the refcount and try to access the buffer without checking it's writability I get a crash. I know this is unsafe and because of that I would like to somehow make the buffer writeable.